# sql query a table grouped by 3 columns and select the distinct values of a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my case : I download CurrecnyExchange Rates from different banks to my DB. I want to filter the rows to see if ExchangeRates differ from banks for a particular day for all combination of currencies Here is my table

[image]

Comment: Explain what output you want.

Comment: Mostpeople here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want days with more than one distinct currency then you can use:

```
select fromid, toid, effdate, count(distinct exchangerate)
from t
group by fromid, toid, effdate
where count(distinct exchangerate) > 0;
```

Comment: Instead of `where` there should be `HAVING`. ;]

Comment: I just do not want the count(distinct exchangeRate) but I want the values itself

Answer (score 0):

This query will transpose your data, for each date you will have `ExchangeRate` from all banks in one row:

```
select FromID, ToID, EffDate,
       max(case when BankID = 1 then ExchangeRate end) AS ExRateBank1,
       max(case when BankID = 2 then ExchangeRate end) AS ExRateBank2,
       max(case when BankID = 3 then ExchangeRate end) AS ExRateBank3
from CurrencyExchange --assumed name, pleasy correct it if not correct
group by FromID, ToID, EffDate
```

And if you want only rows, where rates differ, I suggest following query:

```
select * from (*)
where ExRateBank1 - ExRateBank2 != 0 or ExRateBank1 - ExRateBank3 != 0 or ExRateBank3 - ExRateBank2 != 0
```

where in place of `*` you paste previous query (as a subquery).